# Validation Rules, one of three fields is required

Tags: laravel

I have 3 fields: E-mail, telephone and mobile.

I want to set a validation rules, that one of these 3 fields are required, it doesnt matter which field.

i tried this but it doesnt work, no field is required:

```
public static array $createValidationRules = [
    'email' => 'string|email:rfc,dns|required_without_all:mobile_phone_number,telephone',
    'telephone' => 'max:15|required_without_all:mobile_phone_number,email',
    'mobile_phone_number' => 'max:15|required_without_all:email,telephone',

];


  $validator = Validator::make(request()->input('contact_person'), ContactPerson::getCreateValidationRules());

      if($validator->fails())
         return new Response($validator->errors(),
```

Comment: Bit off topic but you could add an if statement before that checks if the request has at least one of them, if not redirect back with error

Comment: did you try creating a Validation Rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. You were missing `nullable` on email validation. The data `'telephone' => null` would be an invalid email and not a string.

You can quicky verify like this:

```php
Route::get('/test', function ()
{
    $rules = [
        'email'               => 'nullable|string|email:rfc,dns|required_without_all:mobile_phone_number,telephone',
        'telephone'           => 'max:15|required_without_all:mobile_phone_number,email',
        'mobile_phone_number' => 'max:15|required_without_all:email,telephone',
    ];

    $samples = [
        ['email' => null, 'telephone' => null, 'mobile_phone_number' => null],
        [],
        ['email' => 'test@test.com', 'telephone' => null, 'mobile_phone_number' => null],
        ['email' => 'test@test.com', 'telephone' => '000', 'mobile_phone_number' => '000'],
        ['email' => null, 'telephone' => null, 'mobile_phone_number' => '000'],
    ];

    foreach ($samples as $key => $sample) {
        $validator = Validator::make($sample, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){
            dump([$key => $validator->errors()->messages()]);
        }else{
            dump([$key => 'succeed']);
        }
    }
});
```

The first 2 should return a validation error and the last 3 should return "succeed"

Answer (score 1):

I think the above code works perfectly fine. I copied the validation rules and wrote some unit tests and all the test passes.

> `$data` is the set of data that may come from your requests, `$pass` is the `boolean` data if the validation should pass or fail.

> Note: I am running on Laravel 8.76.2 and PHP 8.0

```php
class ValidationTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider validationDataProvider
     *
     * @test
     */
    public function one_of_three_field_is_required($data, $pass)
    {
       $rules = [
            'email'               => 'string|email:rfc,dns|required_without_all:mobile_phone_number,telephone',
            'telephone'           => 'max:15|required_without_all:mobile_phone_number,email',
            'mobile_phone_number' => 'max:15|required_without_all:email,telephone',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        $this->assertEquals($pass, !$validator->fails(), $validator->errors());
    }

    public function validationDataProvider()
    {
        return [
            [[], false],
            [["email" => null], false],
            [["telephone" => null], false],
            [["mobile_phone_number" => null], false],
            [["email" => null, "telephone" => null, "mobile_phone_number" => null], false],
            [["email" => "", "telephone" => "", "mobile_phone_number" => ""], false],
            [["email" => null, "telephone" => null, "mobile_phone_number" => null], false],
            [["email" => null, "telephone" => null, "mobile_phone_number" => null], false],
            [["email" => "test@gmail.com"], true],
            [["telephone" => "1212-14141"], true],
            [["mobile_phone_number" => "12345656172"], true],
            [["email" => "test@gmail.com", "telephone" => "1212", "mobile_phone_number" => "12345656172"], true]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: you are doing `Validator::make(request()->input('contact_person'), ContactPerson::getCreateValidationRules());` is `request()->input('contact_person')` has all the data required ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-without-all)

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are empty or not present.

That means The only time that your code works is when all of the other fields are not present.

You can try with required_without

```php
public static array $createValidationRules = [
    'email' => 'string|email:rfc,dns|required_without:mobile_phone_number,telephone',
    'telephone' => 'max:15|required_without:mobile_phone_number,email',
    'mobile_phone_number' => 'max:15|required_without:email,telephone',
];
```

Now even if telephone is present and mobile_phone_number is not; your email field will be required.

So my guess is one of these fields are present despite you think they're not ( maybe an empty string "" or something ).
You can check this with a simple dd function just before validation.